# How to change fancyheadoffset different for single pages than double digit pages

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

I'm using fancyhdr to position my page numbers in a document (odd/even pages).

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\setlength\footskip{2.0cm}%
\fancyheadoffset[rof,lef]{17mm}%
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\color{KULTgold} \huge \headingfont \thepage}%
```

I got them in the right position vertically but horizontally - single digit pages are slightly off, double digit page numbers look fine.

How can I tweak the position of the page numbers for pages 1...9?

[image: page with single digit]
[image: page with double digits]

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find a solution myself:
putting the page number in a box with center alignment and tweaking the offset number and the box size makes it work

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\setlength\footskip{2.0cm}%
\fancyheadoffset[rof,lef]{15mm}%
\fancyfoot[RO, LE]{\color{KULTgold} \huge \headingfont \makebox[15pt][c]{\thepage}}%
```